# Counting the number of "0" in this factor

Tags: r, string, parsing, pattern-matching

Consider the following factor

```
x = factor(c("1|1","1|0","1|1","1|1","0|0","1|1","0|1"))
```

I would like to count the number of occurrences of the character "0" in this factor. The only solution I've found so far is

```
sum(grepl("0",strsplit(paste(sapply(x, as.character), collapse=""), split="")[[1]]))
# [1] 4
```

This solution seems very complicated for such a simple process. Is there a "better" alternative? (As the process will be repeated about 100,000 times on factors that are 2000 elements long, I might end up caring about performance as well.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
x = factor(c("1|1","1|0","1|1","1|1","0|0","1|1","0|1"))
x
# [1] 1|1 1|0 1|1 1|1 0|0 1|1 0|1
# Levels: 0|0 0|1 1|0 1|1

sum( unlist( lapply( strsplit(as.character(x), "|"), function( x ) length(grep( '0', x ))) ) )
# [1] 4
```

or

```
sum(nchar(gsub("[1 |]", '', x )))
# [1] 4
```

Based on @Rich Scriven's Comment

```
sum(nchar(gsub("[^0]", '', x )))
# [1] 4
```

Based on @thelatemail's comment - using `tabulate` works much faster than the above solution. Here is the comparison.

```
sum(nchar(gsub("[^0]", "", levels(x) )) * tabulate(x))
```

Time Profile:

```
x2 <- sample(x,1e7,replace=TRUE)
system.time(sum(nchar(gsub("[^0]", '', x2 ))));
# user  system elapsed 
# 14.24    0.22   14.65 
system.time(sum(nchar(gsub("[^0]", "", levels(x2) )) * tabulate(x2)));
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.04    0.00    0.04 
system.time(sum(str_count(x2, fixed("0"))))
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.02    0.13    1.25
```

Comment: If you're working on a very big vector, you could save time by operating on the `levels` of `x` only - `sum(nchar(gsub("[^0]", "", levels(x) )) * tabulate(x))`

Comment: @thelatemail thanks. That was wonderful to know. It beats everything

Comment: The key is that the `gsub` only has to operate on `length(levels(x))` instead of `length(x)` - regex is pretty intensive in this case it seems. Having said all that, it's still pretty quick to process 10M records in <15 seconds.

Answer (score 6):

Here are three options.

**Option 1:** `scan()` the vector using `sep="|"`

```
sum(scan(text=as.character(x), sep="|") == 0)
# [1] 4
```

**Option 2:** A fixed character in `gregexpr()`

```
sum(unlist(gregexpr("0", x, fixed=TRUE)) > 0)
# [1] 4
```

**Option 3:** A very simple and fast packaged option with *stringr*

```
library(stringr)
sum(str_count(x, fixed("0")))
# [1] 4
```

Comment: Timings - `set.seed(1); x2 <- sample(x,1e7,replace=TRUE); system.time(sum(nchar(gsub("[^0]", '', x2 )))); system.time(sum(nchar(gsub("[^0]", "", levels(x2) )) * tabulate(x2))); system.time(sum(str_count(x2, fixed("0"))))`

Comment: @thelatemail - That `levels` + `tabulate` one is dreamy